# How can I make reusable JavaScript patterns in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

I am trying to use the pattern property in HTML5 to do Client validation.

However, I find I have to repeate the pattern="\w{2,}" repetitively.

Consider the code below which is part of dart polymer.

```html
<input id='cityTxt'
    type="text"
    required
    pattern="\w{2,}">
```

Is there some mechanism where I could extract the \w{2,}" from the markup and replace it with a variable that I could now use to represent the pattern. This way if I make changes to the pattern it would be only done in a single place rather in multiple places.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If this markup is inside an polymer `<template>` tag, you can use a polymer expression to bind the pattern value to a field of the template model.

```html
<input id='cityTxt'
    type="text"
    required
    pattern="{{aPattern}}">
```

You model provides the field like

```dart
@observable String aPattern = r"\w{2,}";
```